# Meta Data Schemas - Display Type Properties

Tags: content-manager, component

I am new to Tridion and I hope this is a simple question to answer. I am using DD4T in a Visual Studio solution to display the website using content retrieved out of Tridion. Could someone advise what meta-data schemas can be used for? Could I use a meta-data schema to carry across values into the respective DD4T view that maybe not about the content but about the display or are there better ways to achieve something like this?

For example, I create a simple Label schema, in Tridion that contains a text property but I want the content editor to be able to also set the position (i.e. left, right, top, bottom) which is nothing to do with the content of the label? How would I achieve this? What is the best practice of setting display type properties in Tridion?

I hope this makes sense.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Man, you hit it in bull's eye with this one :D
I think that everyone here can give you a different answer to this question.
By definition, one tridion Metadata schema can be added to almost all Tridion items, so you can see that it has multiple usages.

For example:

- you can add it to multimedia component to define data for images like title, alt, author and the rest.
- you can add it o page to have metadata like favicon, google crawler data, or any other metadata that is not defined in component presentations.
- you can add it to folders or structure groups also to be used for translation
- or even you can add it to component and page templates to be used in templating.

It has all kinds of purposes, so it is up to you how you want to use it.